# Integral of $\operatorname{arcsinh}(\frac{x}{a})$, constant of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have been able to show using trigonometric substitution that

$$\int \operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\,dx = \ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\right)-\ln(a)+C$$

However, when I go online to check the answer I notice that the answer is $$\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\right)+C$$ without $\ln(a)$. How do they get this answer? Do they consolidate $-\ln(a)+C$ into a new constant of integration?

Comment: I guess it is that.

Comment: so the $-ln(a)+C$ is treated as a new constant of integration C?

Comment: Yes, $a$ is a fixed constant, $x$ is your variable. So you can take $K=C-\ln(a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are finding an indefinite integral and $\ln(a)$ is a constant. Thus with the constant $C$  there is not need for another constant.

$C- \ln(a)$ is a constant and we might simply drop the $\ln(a)$ part.